# Update Assignee when Jira ticket is created using Azure logic app

Tags: azure, automation, jira, azure-logic-apps, jira-rest-api

I have task for automating ticket assignee on Jira using Azure logic app. When new ticket is created Azure logic app will trigger it and assign ticket to a user.

I tried using the HTTP connector to update the ticket assignee but I got **Bad Request**
[image]

**URL:**

```
https://company.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/{issue_Key}
```

**Body:**

```
  "fields": {
    "assignee": {
      "name": "employee name"
       }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

After reproducing from my end, I could get this work only after including the `accountId` along with `emailAddress` in the request body. Below is the complete request body in my logic app flow.

```
{
"fields": {
    "assignee": {
    "accountId": "63f32c...",
      "emailAddress": "<YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS>"
       }
     }
}
```

[image]

Results:

In Logic App run:

[image]

In Jira dashboard:

[image]

Below is the complete code of my logic app

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "HTTP": {
                "inputs": {
                    "authentication": {
                        "password": "yyy",
                        "type": "Basic",
                        "username": "yyy"
                    },
                    "body": {
                        "fields": {
                            "assignee": {
                                "accountId": "63f32c...",
                                "emailAddress": "yyy"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "PUT",
                    "uri": "https://yyy.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/10004"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Http"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Yep. Because referring to user names directly was deprecated in Jira CLOUD years and years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it is done via the API.
I used JSM automations to solve the problem.
I created an automation within JSM which will update the ticket when it is moved to active and also syncs the assignee.

Maybe you can try something like that :)